# v-repeat is not working with v-if in parent div

Tags: vue.js

I have a conditional div which will be available for user when selected. Inside that div, I need to show a drop down menu using `v-repeat`.

**The problem is** - `v-repeat` is not working with that `v-if` in parent div. When I remove `v-if`, it's showing data perfectly. But when use `v-if`, it's not working.

Moreover, there is no error in console log.

```
 <div class="ui blue segment" v-if="client.legal_status == 'C'">
            <h3 class="ui dividing header">Rappresentante legale</h3>
            <div class="inline fields">
                <div class="two wide field">
                    <label>Nome e Cognome</label>
                </div>
                <div class="seven wide field">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Nome" name="rep_firstname" v-model="client.rep_firstname" />
                </div>
                <div class="seven wide field">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Cognome" name="rep_lastname" v-model="client.rep_lastname" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="inline fields">
                <div class="two wide field">
                    <label>Indirizzo</label>
                </div>
                <div class="fourteen wide field">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Indirizzo" name="rep_address" v-model="client.rep_address" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="inline fields">
                <div class="two wide field">
                    <label>CAP</label>
                </div>
                <div class="two wide field">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="CAP" name="rep_zip_code" v-model="client.rep_zip_code" />
                </div>
                <div class="two wide field">
                    <label>Citt&agrave;</label>
                </div>
                <div class="four wide field">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Città" name="rep_city" v-model="client.rep_city" />
                </div>
                <div class="two wide field">
                    <label>Prov.</label>
                </div>
                <div class="four wide field">

                    <div id="rep_provinces-dropdown" class="ui search selection dropdown">
                        <input type="hidden" name="rep_province_id" v-model="client.rep_province_id">

                        <i class="dropdown icon"></i>

                        <div class="default text">Provincia</div>
                        <div class="menu">
                            <div class="item" v-repeat="province: provinces" data-value="@{{province.id}}">
                                <span class="description">@{{province.id}}</span> @{{province.name}}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="inline fields">
                <div class="two wide field">
                    <label>Cellulare</label>
                </div>
                <div class="six wide field">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Cellulare" name="rep_mobile" v-model="client.rep_mobile" />
                </div>
                <div class="two wide field">
                    <label>Email</label>
                </div>
                <div class="six wide field">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="rep_email" v-model="client.rep_email" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

how can I fix it?

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: code added, please check if it's enough.

Comment: @Jobayer Which version of Vue you are using?

Comment: "vue": "^0.12.16"

Comment: oh wow is there a reason for this version? You should atleast use 1.0 - better 2.0

Comment: This project was developed using that version, old project, is there any way for this version?

Comment: Could you try to change v-if to v-show ? Also are you sure condition is rigt ?

Comment: v-show is working, please post it as a answer.

Comment: using v-show is creating a csrf-token mismatch error while submitting this error, any clue?

Comment: What you are using on backend ? Laravel or something else ? I guess you are using, so please check this https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf - section CSRF Token and Vue

Comment: yes, laravel & also have added <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"> which is working with previously used code, but now with v-show.